# Multiple tabs in Firefox open automatically?

Tags: thunderbird

Whenever I start Thunderbird (17.0),  something starts my 2 installed browsers /FF and Chrome) automatically and opens as many tabs as there are gif or jpeg or ico elements in the first email opened. Sometimes having reached the tab limit (?),  it opens a second or third instance of the browser and chokes my computer with 100% CPU. I have seen as many as 83 open tabs in a >>single<< browser instance. Clearing the browser history doesnt help at all. I changed to a Mint dual boot installation but the "infection" followed me there to both browsers, probably transferred via XMarks.

Whenever I open an email with no graphics, only one tab is opened , seemingly always pointing to favicon.ico from Google.

ClamTK Antivirus show a clean machine.

Anyone with any suggestions??

Environment Ubuntu 12.10 / Unity and Mint 13 /Maya

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the Xmarks extension (and any other extensions you've installed) in Thunderbird.

You may need to delete your Thunderbird profile entirely and start over from scratch.  If your mail is IMAP, this won't be a problem (it will just re-download the mail again).  If you're using POP, you'll need to be sure to back up all the actual mail first.

Comment: I had turned off all TB 17 extensions including Xmarks but this did not help at all. I have rather the feeling that is something to do with my network.protocol-handler settings for http. 2 days ago I had changed to "true" as I wasn't getting any links opened in a browser, and the fix did seemed to work

Comment: I had turned off all TB 17 extensions including Xmarks but this did not help at all. I have rather the feeling that is something to do with my network.protocol-handler settings for http. 2 days ago I had changed to "true" as I wasn't getting any links opened in a browser, and the fix did seemed to work

Comment: please note "You may need to delete your Thunderbird profile entirely and start over from scratch." :)

Comment: Do you mean delete profile.ini ? What recreates it? A new TB start?

Comment: Close Thunderbird, `mv ~/.thunderbird ~/.thunderbird.bak`, and reopen Thunderbird.  You'll have to set up your mail accounts again.  If there's any info that you turn out to be OMG PANICKED TO GET BACK, it'll still be in the `~/.thunderbird.bak` directory to be mined out from there.

Comment: So have now turned off network.protocol-handler.external.http to "false" and the icons are longer mass opening - but no links to browsers from TB email links either